# Sql server with multiple databases

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-bicep

Is it possible to create a sql server with multiple sql databases? How can I create sql server, 3 sql databases using bicep?

Comment: Yes it is possible to create multiple databases: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-bicep-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=CLI.

Comment: you may consider Elastic pools too if satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Please have a look at this: [Quickstart: Create a single database in Azure SQL Database using Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-bicep-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=CLI). You should be able to expand this into what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create sql server, 3 sql databases using bicep?

***You can use below Bicep code referred from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-bicep-quickstart?view=azuresql&tabs=CLI) to deploy Azure SQL Server with 3 Databases.***

**main.bicep code:-**

```json
@description('The name of the SQL logical server.')

param  serverName  string = uniqueString('sql', resourceGroup().id)

  

@description('The name of the SQL Database 1.')

param  sqlDBName  string = 'SampleDB'

  

@description('The name of the SQL Database 2.')

param  sqlDBName1  string = 'SampleDB1'

  

@description('The name of the SQL Database 3.')

param  sqlDBName3  string = 'SampleDB2'

  

@description('Location for all resources.')

param  location  string = resourceGroup().location

  

@description('The administrator username of the SQL logical server.')

param  administratorLogin  string

  

@description('The administrator password of the SQL logical server.')

@secure()

param  administratorLoginPassword  string

  

resource  sqlServer  'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-05-01-preview' = {

name: serverName

location: location

properties: {

administratorLogin: administratorLogin

administratorLoginPassword: administratorLoginPassword

}

}

  

resource  sqlDB  'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {

parent: sqlServer

name: sqlDBName

location: location

sku: {

name: 'Standard'

tier: 'Standard'

}

}

  

resource  sqlDB2  'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {

parent: sqlServer

name: sqlDBName1

location: location

sku: {

name: 'Standard'

tier: 'Standard'

}

}

  
  

resource  sqlDB3  'Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases@2022-05-01-preview' = {

parent: sqlServer

name: sqlDBName3

location: location

sku: {

name: 'Standard'

tier: 'Standard'

}

}
```

**Commands to Deploy the bicep file:-**

```bash
az group create --name exampleRG --location eastus
az deployment group create --resource-group exampleRG --template-file main.bicep --parameters administratorLogin=<admin-login>
```

**Output:-**

[image]